# How to stop a loop in my code? Processing 3

Tags: java, while-loop, processing

So this problem is impossible to explain without you just seeing it for yourself. But here I go. Pretty much I have a random map generator for a game I am making. It is still extremely basic. However I have been stuck on this issue for three days now. Sometimes my code gets stuck in a loop.

So my code has a point that moves around the screen, drawing rectangles behind it, in order to build the map. I have it coded so that the point will never draw two rectangles ontop of eachother. I also have it set so if it is about to draw colliding rectangles, it stops and reroutes itself. Now the issue is sometimes it will draw a circle. Where clearly it can just go out to the side like I programmed it to, however it wont. It will stay there throwing me infinite messages in the output. Its hard to explain so just copy paste my code and it will make a loop about 1/3 runs. I have no idea how to avoid this.

What I have tried:
I have tried detecting when the point reroutes more than 20 times, probably meaning it is stuck, and resetting everything. However it refuses to reset. I specifically programmed the point to go back to its starting point and reset all of the squares, however it does none of that. It appears to just skip over it?
I have also tried completely rewriting my entire algorithm and was able to get it to reset once it detects a loop. However, it would still get stuck in loops MID RESET. I have absolutely no idea why this is happening and need any help I can get. If I seem angry I am. You all probably understand the feeling of having a seemingly simple problem hold you back for a long time. Anything helps, thanks!

Here is my code, I am not going to shorten it because this issue is specific to THIS code and as I stated it is extremely hard to describe. Just copy paste it:

```
int gx = 400;
int gy = 400;
int gDir;
int gCheckX;
int gCheckY;
int[] rx = new int[30];
int[] ry = new int[30];
int i = -1;
int whileCount = 0;

void setup() {
  size(700, 700);
  while(i < 29) {
    i++;
    rx[i] = -100;
  }
  i = -1;
}

void draw() {
  fill(0);
  rect(0, 0, width, height);
  fill(#696969);
  fill(#696969);
  rect(rx[0], ry[0], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[1], ry[1], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[2], ry[2], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[3], ry[3], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[4], ry[4], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[5], ry[5], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[6], ry[6], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[7], ry[7], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[8], ry[8], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[9], ry[9], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[10], ry[10], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[11], ry[11], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[12], ry[12], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[13], ry[13], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[14], ry[14], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[15], ry[15], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[16], ry[16], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[17], ry[17], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[18], ry[18], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[19], ry[19], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[20], ry[20], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[21], ry[21], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[22], ry[22], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[23], ry[23], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[24], ry[24], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[25], ry[25], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[26], ry[26], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[27], ry[27], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[28], ry[28], 50, 50);
  rect(rx[29], ry[29], 50, 50);
  if(i < 29) {
    i++;
    gDir = int(random(1, 5));
    if(gDir == 1) {
      gCheckX = 25;
      gCheckY = -25;
    }
    if(gDir == 2) {
      gCheckX = 25;
      gCheckY = 75;
    }
    if(gDir == 3) {
      gCheckX = -25;
      gCheckY = 25;
    }
    if(gDir == 4) {
      gCheckX = 75;
      gCheckY = 25;
    }
    whileCount = 0;
    while(get(gx + gCheckX, gy + gCheckY) == color(105, 105, 105) || gx + gCheckX > width - 50 || gx + gCheckX < 50 || gy + gCheckY > height - 50 || gy + gCheckY < 50) {
      whileCount++;
      println("While Activated " + whileCount);
      gDir = int(random(1, 5));
      if(gDir == 1) {
        gCheckX = 25;
        gCheckY = -25;
      }
      if(gDir == 2) {
        gCheckX = 25;
        gCheckY = 75;
      }
      if(gDir == 3) {
        gCheckX = -25;
        gCheckY = 25;
      }
      if(gDir == 4) {
        gCheckX = 75;
        gCheckY = 25;
      }
    }
    if(gDir == 1) {gy -= 50;}
    if(gDir == 2) {gy += 50;}
    if(gDir == 3) {gx -= 50;}
    if(gDir == 4) {gx += 50;}
    rx[i] = gx;
    ry[i] = gy;
    println(rx[i] + " " + ry[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: is it writtent in any programming language? It doesnt look as pseoudo code (maybe a little). so. please, add a label with language you are using , then you will got more traffic in your question

Comment: So, I don't know what language it is. It's processing so it is built off of java but it is obviously not java. I have no clue

Comment: the `setup` function looks a bit like arduino function, but that's a blind (and probably incorrect) guess. Try declaring the `i` var in `setup` function maybe (just guessing).

Comment: It is extremely similar to java so java is by far the closes language

Comment: ok, the thing here is we cannot see where and how  the `setup` and  `draw` functions are called. Regardless that, there're 2 while functions and I bet the `while` in `draw` doesn't stop. Maybe try adding a `whileCount < yourLimit` as additional condition or `if` statement like `if (condition) { break; }`. (Still guessing, Minimal Reproducible Example would be much helpful).

Comment: @itwasntme Read tag <[processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info)> info. [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts. Processing is based  on Java

Comment: The void setup is a built in function that runs instantly right when the program starts and void draw is a loop that runs 60 times a second throughout the duration of the program